# How to send POST request to JIRA for creating a Project through REST api

Tags: c#, rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

I am working on integration JIRA api, how can i create a new project into JIRA through api

from api documentation i can see end points for listing the projects and some other project related activity, but there is no any end point to create a new project into the JIRA.

i have attached a piece of [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Tutorials) screenshot, in the screenshot there is no any POST url mentioned for creating the project.[image].

For completing my work i am using c#.Net with console based application.

**Please help me what i can do into it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Project is not supported yet for REST API. Here's [a link](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/169528/create-project-with-jira-api) as of 2013, and I am not sure if they got it now. Please search over to find if they got it in newer versions.
You might have to create a project first in the web application, and work with creating and editing issues etc from your API client.
Hope this helps!

Comment: user2406649 you are right, creation of project is not possible yet in JIRA api, i have not solved my query yet so i am giving your answer as upvote, recently it is not supported by JIRA. But later they will release the solution of the project creation into the JIRA from the REST API.

Thank you :) (Y)

Answer (score 1):

To create a project using REST API in Jira is now supported.

Follow the link below.
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#api-api-2-project-post